# How multilevel Bayesian models handle group imbalance

Tags: bayesian, unbalanced-classes, hierarchical-bayesian

I’ve read that partial pooling (multilevel / hierarchical models) can balance the extremes: on one hand, zero pooling where every group receives its own parameters, non influenced by other groups. And full pooling, where is one group has more data (or outliers) it can dominate the posterior distribution.

I’m curious how partial pooling doesn’t revolve into the full pooling scenario?

For example, consider that one group produces 5x the data that other groups produce. As I understand it, this group would not dominate the posterior distribution to the extend that would be realized in a fully pooled model.

However, I don’t understand why. Each group has its own parameters and they’re drawn from common prior distributions.

But wouldn’t the observations with more data points dominate these inferred prior distributions, devolving into the fully pooled model?